# How to extract the file name of a pdf link including numbers using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I have the following url string:

```
"https://www.stadt-koeln.de/mediaasset/content/pdf13/amtsblatt/amtsblaetter-2022/amtsblatt_05_20220209.pdf"
```

How can I use regular expression to get the filename of an url?
I have tried:

```
text = "https://www.stadt-koeln.de/mediaasset/content/pdf13/amtsblatt/amtsblaetter-2022/amtsblatt_05_20220209.pdf"

text = re.sub("/[^/]*$", '', text)
text
```

but I am receiving:

```
'https://www.stadt-koeln.de/mediaasset/content/pdf13/amtsblatt/amtsblaetter-2022'
```

The desired output is:

```
"amtsblatt_05_20220209.pdf"
```

I am thankful for any advice.

Comment: It would probably be easier to use pythons string [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function instead of a regex. For example: `file_name = text.split('/')[-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with:

```
import re

text = "https://www.stadt-koeln.de/mediaasset/content/pdf13/amtsblatt/amtsblaetter-2022/amtsblatt_05_20220209.pdf"

pdf_name = re.findall("/[^/]*$", text)[0]
print(pdf_name)
```

or simple with:

```
pdf_name = text.split('/')[-1]
print(pdf_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you exactly want to use regex then try

```
re.findall(r"/(\w+\.pdf)", text)[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to regular expressions, which may make it more clear what the intend is

```py
import urllib
import pathlib

text = "https://www.stadt-koeln.de/mediaasset/content/pdf13/amtsblatt/amtsblaetter-2022/amtsblatt_05_20220209.pdf"
filename = pathlib.Path(urllib.parse.urlparse(text).path).name
```

Or with additional package `urplath`

```py
import urlpath

filename = urlpath.URL(text).name
```

---

As an answer why your approach did not work

```
re.sub("/[^/]*$", '', text)
```

This does find your desired string, but it then **sub**stitutes it with nothing, so it removes what you have found. You'd probably wanted to either find the string

```
>>> re.search("/[^/]*$", text).group()
'/amtsblatt_05_20220209.pdf'
# Without the leading /
>>> re.search("/([^/]*)$", text).group(1)
'amtsblatt_05_20220209.pdf'
```

Or you wanted to discard everything that is not the filename

```
>>> re.sub("^.*/(?!=[^\/]+$)", "", text)
'amtsblatt_05_20220209.pdf'
```